# When was Shion's flashback of him and his father camping set at?

Tags: darker-than-black

In the first flashback, we see a meteor shower; since Shion was a contractor since he was born, this would mean that the false sky was already in place. To my knowledge, there are only two events that had a lot of contractors die (thus showing a lot of stars falling): One was Heaven's War, and the other is the events at the end of the first season.

When Shion's flashbacks occurred, was it during Heaven's War, or the end of the first season (which I like to refer to as Hell's War)?

Answer (score 1):

The original Suou died 8 years before *Ryūsei no Jemini*, which is set two years after the first season. Izanamis stopped awakening in the OVA, which was 6 years after human Suou died. Logically, Suou has to have died during Heaven's War.

Comment: i was asking when Shion's flashback of the meteor shower was since both he and his father saw the meteor shower (there was no Suou) and it symbolized the deaths of many contractors which there are only 2 times it happens, Heaven's War and the end of the first Season, while your answer does state that Suou have to have died during Heaven's War that unfortunately does not indicate which meteor shower Shion saw

Comment: Apologies maybe i read incorrectly. Did you mean when he had the flash back or when the flashback was from? Shion has no presence in the tokyo incident so it would make not sense for flashbacks to be at or from that time.

Comment: when the flashback was from, also the flashback could have been from the same time as the Tokyo Incident as i'm sure the flashback wasn't set in the same country as where Heaven's War took place either unless there was a 3rd incident which would cause starts to fall like that, and sorry for the late replay, i got no notifications about you replay to my post so i never check back at the question